# TCP connection through CAsyncSocket is not working: onConnect never called

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, visual-c++, service

**Existing scenario is explained below.**

Our application is running on Client Server architecture; Client is developed with VC++ and Server is developed with C#.
On the Server side there are two exe's running (myServer1.exe -Windows service based, and myServer2.exe -Windows application). myServer2.exe is communicating to myServer1.exe through TCP socket connection.
On the Client side, an exe (myApp1.exe -Windows Service based) runs another exe based on user sessions present in the machine (myUser.exe for all user sessions). Every myUser.exe instances are communicating to myApp1.exe through PIPE communication. And myApp1.exe is also communicating to myServer1.exe through another TCP communication.

**New scenario.**

We are now creating a TCP socket in listening mode in myServer2.exe (Server application -C#). myUser.exe (Client application -VC++) is trying to connect to myServer2.exe through a TCP connection by using `CAsyncSocket`. But the framework calls (`OnConnect`, `OnReceive` and `OnClose`) are not happening.

Socket creation-   `Create(0,SOCK_STREAM); // CAyncSocket`

Socket connection-  `Connect("ServerIP", "ServerPort"); // CAsyncSocket`

Note: when we move the socket creation and connection functionalities into Windows service based exe (myApp1.exe), the connection works fine, OnConnect OnReceive and OnClose are happening.

**Why framework call to OnConnect is not happening** in myUser.exe while in myApp1.exe is?

Comment: so basically, you have a C# windows server application and many VC++ clients and you want them to communicate via TCP right? Share some code

Comment: As of now the communication between the server and the clients are working fine. Problem is that I want to create a socket in the myUser.exe with sending mode and the myServer2.exe will be listening to the same.But the notification functions (Onconnect, OnSend etc) on the myUser.exe(VC++) is not happening. Always getting the socket error 10035 (The operation should be retired later). But we tried several times and still getting the same error. So the 'CAsyncSocket::Connect' always failing.

Answer (score 0):

Your `OnConnect` method is not called because probably **you don't have the message loop** in myUser.exe while you have it in myApp.exe.

Error code 10035 is `WSAEWOULDBLOCK` and it' normal for your case, from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tbz7kf5.aspx):

> It is normal for WSAEWOULDBLOCK to be reported as the result from
>   calling connect on a nonblocking SOCK_STREAM socket, since some time
>   must elapse for the connection to be established.

So don't worry about it. If you have a message loop, after your `Connect` call, the `OnConnect` method will finally be called at a certain time with a successful result or with an error code.

See also [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617847/CAsyncsocket-and-Console-with-MFC-TCP) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975442/casyncsocket-not-firing-events)

Comment: When we initiate a TCP communication between myApp1.exe(VC++)  and myServer2.exe (C#), everything is working fine. So my question is what would be the exact problem causing this issue??

Comment: @Jose. TCP communication is working fine when started from myApp1.exe, while it is not working when started from myUser.exe: right? Both are written in VC++. Do they share the same code for opening the TCP connection? See my updated answer

Comment: Yes. Both myApp1.exe and myUser.exe are sharing the same VC++ code.

Comment: When myApp1.exe is in listening mode all the notifications are fired. But on sending mode CAsyncSocket not firing the events.

Comment: @Jose. If you use the same class for managing TCP connection, then there must be a difference in the code using it. MyApp is a service app while MyUser is a console app? Anyway for some reason you don't have the message loop in MyUser that's why notifications are not fired